# How do I create a live windows USB?

Tags: windows, usb

first off, I am not sure if *superuser* is the right place to post this. If not, please redirect me :). I need to create a "live", persistent Windows 10 environment without the Enterprise Edition. (Sort of like the Try mode on an Ubuntu install disk) I have tried to do this:

1. Created a Windows 10 ISO with the MediaCreationTool
2. Formatted my SanDisk 64gb USB
3. Mounted the ISO and extracted /sources/install.esd
4. Used wimlib to apply install.esd to USB drive with following command:
   `.\wimlib-imagex.exe apply install.esd J:\`
5. Marked partition as Active in DiskManager
6. Created boot files with following commands (USB drive is on letter J:)

```
> J:
> cd Windows\System32
> bcdboot.exe J:\Windows /s J: /f ALL
```

Then, I tried to boot into this Live USB (UEFI mode), but as it was booting, it showed this error message:

`Attempting Boot from USB Device`
`isolinux.bin missing or corrupt`

I am not sure what to do next. Can anyone spot the issue? Thank you so much.

Comment: another method>>>>>https://www.pcmag.com/article/352209/how-to-run-windows-10-from-a-usb-drive

Comment: Ty, will take a look

Comment: another here>>>>>https://www.howtogeek.com/196817/how-to-create-a-windows-to-go-usb-drive-without-the-enterprise-edition/

Comment: HowToGeek is the one I used